# Facebook api: List facebook users who work or worked for company / page

Tags: facebook, api

Does anyone know of a way to list facebook users that say on their profile that they work at a given company? or used to work at the company.
Not sure if its even possible as i cant find anything in the api docs about this for the page object.

Comment: **Update**: Looks like this currently isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

you can get only those info about the user those are public in there profile.

for more info visit here
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/

Comment: Hi Maneesh, thanks but im aware you can get this on the User objects, but im looking for a way to relate a page / company back to a user.